# PHP COM object DLL error

Tags: php, object, dll, com

I've created a ComVisible DLL file with C#. The DLL's code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace deneme
{
     [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Class1
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "HelloDLL";
        }
         [ComVisible(true)]
        static string Hello()
        {
            return "dEnEmE";
        }
    }
}
```

I've registered the DLL with RegAsm to registry.
And this is my PHP code.

```
<?

try{
  $com = new COM('deneme.Class1');
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'error: ' . $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

When I try to open this DLL's HelloWorld function on PHP, system throws an exception like "**error: Failed to create COM object `deneme.Class1': Çok zararlı hata**". The translation of "Çok zararlı hata" is : Very harmful error :)

Can you help me with doing that?
I'm using Windows 7 IIS + PHP + MySQL.

Best regards.

Comment: We need more info I'm afraid.  Does it really mean Very Harmful Error or Catastrophic Failure!  Your C# COM object isn't being created properly.